# combining two htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a problem and find no answer by myself, so maybe someone can help me.

i have this url:
www.horden-des-chaos.de
it has its own .htaccess file

```
# These folders will not be touched.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/css/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/js/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/img/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Then have your redirect rule
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now there is a directory called "/forum/" (http://www.horden-des-chaos.de/forum/)
There is a full installation of a forumsoftware (SimpleMachinesForum) with an "prettyurl" addon, which created this .htaccess

```
# PRETTYURLS MOD BEGINS
# Pretty URLs mod
# http://code.google.com/p/prettyurls/
# .htaccess file generated automatically on: February 3, 2014, 12:18

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rules for: actions
RewriteRule ^(activate|admin|announce|attachapprove|buddy|calendar|clock|collapse)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(coppa|credits|deletemsg|display|dlattach|editpoll|editpoll2|emailuser)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(findmember|groups|help|helpadmin|im|jseditor|jsmodify|jsoption)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(lock|lockvoting|login|login2|logout|markasread|mergetopics|mlist)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(moderate|modifycat|modifykarma|movetopic|movetopic2|notify|notifyboard|openidreturn)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(pm|post|post2|printpage|profile|quotefast|quickmod|quickmod2)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(recent|register|register2|reminder|removepoll|removetopic2|reporttm|requestmembers)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(restoretopic|search|search2|sendtopic|shoutbox|smstats|suggest|spellcheck)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(splittopics|stats|sticky|theme|trackip|about:mozilla|about:unknown|unread)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(unreadreplies|verificationcode|viewprofile|vote|viewquery|viewsmfile|who|\.xml)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(xmlhttp)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;action=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: boards
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1.$2 [L,QSA]

# Rules for: topics
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.0 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([-_!~*'()$a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([0-9]*|msg[0-9]*|new)/?$ ./index.php?pretty;board=$1;topic=$2.$3 [L,QSA]

# PRETTYURLS MOD ENDS
```

I can get that www.horden-des-chaos/forum/ is callable and shows the index of the forum, but if i call www.horden-des-chaos/forum/offentliche-news/ i get redirected to the index of www.horden-des-chaos.de instead of the called forum.

Any Ideas how to solve it?
It works finde with the forum sub domain (forum.horden-des-chaos.de) but i which to use the same url for both.

PS: I am not a native english speaker, i tried my best :/

Comment: is there an htaccess file in the offentliche directory?

Comment: nope, its no "real" directory its just a readable url

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the forum sub-directory from your original rewrite:

```
# These folders will not be touched.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/css/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/js/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/img/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Then have your redirect rule
# RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/_]+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Regards